# Modal JDialog shows empty frame. Contained Panels are not showing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, swingx

Okay so I've successfully created a modal `JDialog` and I used Netbeans GUI Builder to create panels to speed up the design. However, the modal `JDialog` doesn't show the panels it has, therefore empty. I don't know what to do next and I don't see any reason why it won't show up if the main container does show.

`JDialog` is expected to come up after 2 mouse clicks on `JTable`

[image]

What comes up is this.

[image]

instead of this (Update Curriculum Gui), below.

[image]

```
private void curriculumListJtblMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                
        int clickCount = evt.getClickCount();
        if (clickCount == 2) {
            UpdateCurriculumGui updateCurriculum = new UpdateCurriculumGui();
            updateCurriculum.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 650));
            updateCurriculum.setVisible(true);
            updateCurriculum.pack();
            updateCurriculum.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    }
```

UpdateCurriculumGui on it's own class.

```
public class UpdateCurriculumGui extends javax.swing.JDialog {



    public UpdateCurriculumGui() {
        super(null, ModalityType.MODELESS);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setTitle("Update Curriculum Information");
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me because I haven't tried to use JDialogs before. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fill your dialog with content!

```
public class UpdateCurriculumGui extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public UpdateCurriculumGui() {
        super(null, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        //setAlwaysOnTop(true); set modal instead
        setTitle("Update Curriculum Information");
        add(new JLabel("i'm content!"));  //this is content!      
    }
}
```

see [Dialog.ModalityType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) for details on `MODELESS` (shouldn't it be `APPLICATION_MODAL` ?)

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry because I just realized how little the problem is. I accidentally removed the initComponents() which constructs the panels I created. This happened when I created a new constructor. I just had to call initComponents() again and that fixed it. I see the panels within the JDialog now.

Comment: i'm very glad other people have the same problems as i do have =) good luck for your project!

Comment: Yeah thanks. Sometimes when you get so focused on difficult things, you miss the easiest. I appreciate it.